# Can you make an OS only using assembly language?

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, nasm, cross-compiling, osdev

I am making an OS on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), but setting up cross compilers is to difficult (other questions did not help). Is it possible to make an OS only in assembly to avoid C or C++ cross-compilers?

PS: Is there a good cross-compiling resource for Ubuntu 64 bit to i386:x86_64 please let me know.

Comment: Of course it's possible, but not very practical unless you have no choice. Too many fiddly details to keep track of that a compiler does with ease. And you would still need a cross-assembler, right?

Comment: No, I do not need a cross-assembler because Nasm compiles into the right format/architecture.

Comment: Many early operating systems, including the famous MS-DOS were written completely in assembly.  Modern examples include MenuetOS.  So yes, it's perfectly possible.

Comment: *compiles into the right format/architecture* -> the definition of a cross-assembler. But are you sure NASM fits here? it only supports x86 AFAIK. Oh, If you're not on an x86 platform then it should make sense.

Comment: I am not real in the know about compilers but from what I can tell I only installed nasm and run is with ‘nasm -fbin boot.asm -o boot.bin’

Comment: What is *"i836:x86_64"*? A particular instruction set? What is "i836"? Do you mean *"[i386](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I386)"* (swapped "3" and "8") ([IA-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32))?

Comment: Yes, I meant i386

Comment: Unless I'm very  mistaken, most compilers produce assembly language to be converted to executable machine code, rather than producing executable machine code directly.

Comment: Nasm is not a compiler, it is a assembler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct but useless answer is - yes, it's possible. Anything C/C++ does, assembly can do, too. If your next question is - how, the only possible answer would be "read a book". This is a small question with a book length answer. Yes, anything you can code in C/C++ you can also code in assembly... but it will take you 10 times longer, especially with debugging.

That aside, putting together a working OS in assembly will be an order of magnitude more complicated and time consuming than setting up cross compilation. If that is a challenge for you, maybe you shouldn't tackle a whole OS just yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you know of any resources to setup cross-compiling on Ubuntu please let me know.

Comment: Putting  together a working OS in a high level language is an order of magnitude more complicated  than installing a cross compiler. Doing it in assembly language is an additional order of magnitude harder. :-)

Comment: A bit late to the party, but the OSDev.org wiki page on [GCC Cross Compiling](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) should work on any compatible Unix-like OS, and is written with Linux specifically in mind. Since Ubuntu is one of the most prevalent Linux distros, the information should be well suited to it. The instructions are mainly geared towards a 32-bit OS on x86, but it should be possible to adjust it to work for any 32 or 64 bit architecture by changing the target triplets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Indeed, this used to be common before Unix which introduced portability of operating systems across architectures. Operating systems like Digital Equipment's [RSX-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSX-11) were written in assembler. A somewhat famous academic example is Alexia Massalin's 1992 [Synthesis kernel](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/nyu/04fa/sched/readings/synthesis.pdf), a small kernel with a Unix compatibility layer. It was written in Motorola 68020 assembly and represented a minor rebellion against high level language OSes. It was very fast for its time.

Comment: Some multi-threading operating systems made for mini-computers back in the 1970's, and for multi-threading embedded systems in the 1980's were done in assembler.

Comment: Unix itself was originally written in assembly for PDP-11, or at least the earliest development started that way.  C was developed later as part of porting it to other systems and making it more maintainable, if I'm remembering the history correctly.  But yes, early Unix used C as a portable assembly language.